# Why isn't Indigo soluble in water?

Tags: solubility, hydrogen-bond

Why isn't Indigo soluble in water? I mean, it has 2 H-N groups, shouldn't it then be able to hydrogen bond with water?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

True, Indigo can form hydrogen bonds, but with what? Is it water? Nope.

It makes hydrogen bonds with **itself**.

[image]

This makes the molecule incapable of bonding with water. Not only that, but the molecule itself is **quite symmetric**, with oppositely oriented polar bonds, that cancel out each others' dipole moments. Notice the molecule's similarity to an ace of diamonds:

[image]

This type of symmetry is called **center of symmetry** as it is about it's center we can observe the symmetry.

So we got it, it can't associate itself with water, and it's nonpolar. What do we expect? **It doesn't dissolve in water**.

Comment: Yes, and the lone pair of Nitrogen is interacting with $\pi$ system of the ring, so it diminished more the nucleophilicity(i am  not sure if it is a correct word). Nice reasoning about the dipolar moment. It can be done "rigurously" by symmetry theory also.

Comment: Thank you  for the elaborate answer. I was aware of it's symmetry, it's just the hydrogen bonding that puzzled me, thank you.